# Able to fetch users but not able to fetch mailFolders details for particular users present in the same tenant from graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am not able fetch mailFolders details for some user present in my tenant and I m able to fetch the user info.Using graph explorer to fetch details.

On top of that I have tried fetching mailFolders details for my admin account in the tenant (logged in with admin account) and it was successful.

I have already given the required permission to my application. Mail.read and Mail.ReadBasic.All. Both are the application permission.

Users are added into my Azure Active Directory as well as app.

The API GET URL is this one -

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*****@******.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders

I am trying to fetch other user mailFolders while logged in with an admin account of that tenant, but getting the error Access Denied.

[Error Access Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvXax.png)

How do I fix this?
I tried adding users to graph app in Azure enterprise applications but this also didn't help.
I also modified mailbox permission on the Admin console for some of the users but this also didn't help.

Please help

Regards,
Apoorv.

Answer (score 0):

There is still one permission is missing I think in the permissions tab "Mail.ReadWrite"

[image]

Also please check the token if the required scopes are present in there in https://jwt.ms/

Comment: I have added that permission too, but same result is seen. Why do we even Mail.ReadWrite permission for just to fetch mailFolders?